# Find a hole while travelling along an infinite wall

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

There is an infinite wall with a hole somewhere, you are placed on that wall at an unknown position. Let the distance between your initial position & the hole be $x$. Find the average distance traveled in terms of $x$ until you find the hole. What's the complexity of this problem in terms of $x$ and how does an algorithm look like that solves it?

Comment: This looks like the standard [lost cow problem](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node622.html).

Comment: One is placed "at a random position" with what distribution? $\hspace{2.3 in}$ How does the hole's size compare to the wall's height? $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: I suspect "random" actually means "arbitrary", that the "wall" is actually a line, and that "you" are actually a point.  But I'm happy to be corrected.

Comment: In that case, bludger should still say whether he's considering randomized $\hspace{1.45 in}$ or only deterministic search strategies. $\:$

Comment: @JeffE: Could you summarize this in a short answer?

Comment: If I am not mistaken then you actually have two choices in the begining. Go "left" or go "right". If the hole is distanced exactly $x$ from you, then a hole may be to the "left" or to the "right" with (I suppose) equal probability $=\frac{1}{2}$. Expected travel length is then $E=\frac{x}{2}x+\frac{3x}{2}=x$.

Answer (score 1):

If you can go only left or right, than you can do the following strategy:

```
DIRECTION = Right
For i = 0 to infinity do:
    Go 2^i steps to DIRECTION.
    Go back to the initial place.
    CHANGE_DIRECTION
    STOP if you found the hole
```

If the distance between the start place and the hole is n, you will find the hole within O(n) steps. You can easily calculate the exact average number of steps given this algorithm.